# I can ssh to remote virtual machine but I can't ping it

Tags: centos, ssh, virtual-machines

I have been provided a remote virtual machine running Centos 7 and I have to setup a web server on it. I can access the machine via ssh but I cannot ping it and I cannot access the test web page that I created (Apache is running). I made some checks:

- ifconfig on the virtual machine:

  ```
  eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1400
  inet 192.168.209.7  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 192.168.211.255
  inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe35:cdfb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
  ether fa:16:3e:35:cd:fb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
  RX packets 110329  bytes 454155776 (433.1 MiB)
  RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
  TX packets 65991  bytes 7412428 (7.0 MiB)
  TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
  ```
- iptables on the virtual machine:

  ```
  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 85851 packets, 450M bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source      destination         

  Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source      destination         

  Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 46405 packets, 3382K bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source      destination
  ```
- `nmap -Pn -PS80 <remote ip>` on the client machine (running ubuntu

  ```
  Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-01-28 11:20 CET
  Nmap scan report for <remote ip>
  Host is up (0.043s latency).
  Not shown: 999 filtered ports
  PORT   STATE SERVICE
  22/tcp open  ssh

  Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.00 seconds
  ```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You are trying to `nmap <remote-ip>`. Is that different from `192.168.209.7` which seems to be the IP address of the VM? Are you trying to connect from within the `192.168.208.0/22` subnet or from outside?

Comment: I am connecting from outside and <remote ip> is different (and it is the same that I use for ssh). Is there any other check that I can make?

Comment: Nope, not needed. If you connect to an external IP which is different from `192.168.209.7` then the external IP ( maybe the router ) does not forward the port to the internal IP address.

Comment: This virtual machine has a firewall external to the machine. You will need to check the external firewall.

Comment: Then why can i connect via ssh? And what ip should I use for ping/apache access?

Comment: The firewall will probably block ICMP-echo, but will permit ssh. If you want apache access, you should permit 80/443 on the firewall; if you want to ping you should allow the ICMP's.

Comment: I only have access to the vm. Is it something I can do or should I ask to the System administrator?

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. This is not a forum; questions should not contain answers or the word "SOLVED" or similar words. Instead, answers should be posted below as an answer, and then ticked to indicate that the answer solved the problem.